# Installed plugin version not showing

Tags: google-chrome, plugins, npapi

I made a web plugin using NPAPI for Google Chrome, Firefox on Linux.

I would like to show what version is installed on installed plugin list, so `NP_GetPluginVersion()` is added to see. Firefox works but Chrome does not.

For instance, Adobe Flash Player displays a version with the plugin name and description.

```
Adobe Flash Player-Version: 11.5.31.5
Shockwave Flash 11.5 r31
```

Can some one please help me to solve my issue?

Is there another way as `Info.plist` is used for Chrome plugin version on Mac?

Comment: Does chrome show the version of other plugins in about:plugins? is it just yours that doesn't display?

Comment: Yes. The version of my plugins is not shown on Chrome in chrome://plugins. For instance, adobe flash player display a version. It seems for me to miss something.

Comment: For reference on webkit/blink missing plugin.version: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=36667

Answer (score 0):

We had to append the version to the end of our Plugin Description and parse it via JavaScript as a work around in Chrome.